# STL vector implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, vectors

I've implemented a simple vector-like structure.  I would appreciate all criticism relevant to code, style, flow, camelCase vs underscore, and so forth.

```
template <class T>
class  Vector {
public:

    typedef T* Iterator;

    Vector();
    Vector(unsigned int size);
    Vector(unsigned int size, const T & initial);
    Vector(const Vector<T>& v);
    ~Vector();

    unsigned int capacity() const;
    unsigned int size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
    T& front();
    T& back();
    void push_back(const T& value);
    void pop_back();

    void reserve(unsigned int capacity);
    void resize(unsigned int size);

    T & operator[](unsigned int index);
    Vector<T> & operator = (const Vector<T> &);
    void clear();
private:
    unsigned int _size;
    unsigned int _capacity;
    unsigned int Log;
    T* buffer;
};

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector() {
    _capacity = 0;
    _size = 0;
    buffer = 0;
    Log = 0;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T> & v) {
    _size = v._size;
    Log = v.Log;
    _capacity = v._capacity;
    buffer = new T[_size];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size) {
    _size = size;
    Log = ceil(log((double) size) / log(2.0));
    _capacity = 1 << Log;
    buffer = new T[_capacity];
}

template <class T>
bool Vector<T>:: empty() const {
    return _size == 0;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size, const T& initial) {
    _size = size;
    Log = ceil(log((double) size) / log(2.0));
    _capacity = 1 << Log;
    buffer = new T [_capacity];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        buffer[i] = initial;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator = (const Vector<T> & v) {
    delete[] buffer;
    _size = v._size;
    Log = v.Log;
    _capacity = v._capacity;
    buffer = new T [_capacity];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::begin() {
    return buffer;
}

template<class T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::end() {
    return buffer + size();
}

template<class T>
T& Vector<T>::front() {
    return buffer[0];
}

template<class T>
T& Vector<T>::back() {
    return buffer[_size - 1];
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T & v) {
    /*
        Incidentally, one common way of regrowing an array is to double the size as needed.
        This is so that if you are inserting n items at most only O(log n) regrowths are performed
        and at most O(n) space is wasted.
    */
    if (_size >= _capacity) {
        reserve(1 << Log);
        Log++;
    }
    buffer [_size++] = v;
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back() {
    _size--;
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::reserve(unsigned int capacity) {
    T * newBuffer = new T[capacity];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        newBuffer[i] = buffer[i];

    _capacity = capacity;
    delete[] buffer;
    buffer = newBuffer;
}

template<class T>
unsigned int Vector<T>::size() const {
    return _size;
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::resize(unsigned int size) {
    Log = ceil(log((double) size) / log(2.0));
    reserve(1 << Log);
    _size = size;
}

template<class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index) {
    return buffer[index];
}

template<class T>
unsigned int Vector<T>::capacity()const {
    return _capacity;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector() {
    delete[] buffer;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::clear() {
    _capacity = 0;
    _size = 0;
    buffer = 0;
    Log = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code is C++03 like (ie there are no move constructors or move assignment operators). You should definitely think about updating your class to be move aware.

The first thing about the interface is that the assignment operator is not close to the constructors. Since these are highly linked I like to place the assignment operators very close to the constructors (see rule of three/five).

Using `_` as a prefix is a bad idea. You **don't** break any rules (but was this on purpose or just an accident?). The rules are sufficiently complex that prefix `_` on identifiers is a bad idea for user space code. Others have suggested a prefix like `m_` personally I think that is old school advice. As long as the naming is clear there should be no issues.

My personal convention with identifiers is that anything that can be an object starts with a lowercase letter. Anything that is a type begins with an uppercase letter. Others will disagree with this convention as the standard does not follow it and this can lead to other conflicts.

Here is one of those exceptions to my rules.

```
    typedef T* Iterator;
```

You should probably have iterator with a lowercase `i`. This is because a lot of the algorithms will use the type.

Good start.

```
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
    T& front();
    T& back();
    T & operator[](unsigned int index);
```

But you will need const versions of all these (and a `const_iterator` type) to be a fully compliant container.

You are going to have a hard time making this work if the buffer is of type T. Every time you expand the buffer all the elements in the buffer will be initialized with `T` constructor. For `int` this is not a problem. But if `T` has a non trivial constructor then you are going to pay a heavy price initializing elements that may never be used.

```
T* buffer;
```

Really the buffer should be something that does not have a constructor.

```
char* buffer;
```

Prefer the initializer list.

```
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector() {
    _capacity = 0;
    _size = 0;
    buffer = 0;
    Log = 0;
}

// This will also warn about out of order initialization.
// Not a big thing but it keeps your thinking logical.

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
    : _size(0)
    , _capacity(0)
    , Log(0)
    // Personally I would always allocate some space for the buffer
    // even if the size is zero. This way I do not have to worry about
    // the special case of buffer ever being a NULL pointer.
    //
    // Having a special case of NULL will affect all the methods and make
    // the code much more complex. Reduce code complexity means easier to
    // maintain code.
    //
    , buffer(new char[sizeof(T) * capacity])
    // Note this assumes buffer is (char* as described above)
{}
```

Again. Use an initializer list.

```
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T> & v) {
    _size = v._size;
    Log = v.Log;
    _capacity = v._capacity;
```

Do you really mean to allocate `_size` memebers to the buffer. Should this not be `_capacity`?

```
    buffer = new T[_size];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
}
```

Also use the internal algorithms to help you.

```
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> const& v)
 // Note. I put cost here   ^^^^^   most of the time it does not matter.
 // There is one corner case where it does.
    : _size(v._size)
    , _capacity(v._capacity)
    , Log(v.Log)
    , buffer(new char[sizeof(T) * _capacity])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        // Now you can use placement new to copy the elements from
        // source into the current vector.
        new (buffer + sizeof(T) * i) T(v[i]);
    }
}
```

Again use initializer list.

```
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size) {
    _size = size;
```

This seems to be a constant. I would just make this a constant of the class and calculate it once by hand. The use of these maths functions seems a bit like overkill to me.

```
    Log = ceil(log((double) size) / log(2.0));
    _capacity = 1 << Log;
    buffer = new T[_capacity];
}
```

Personally one liners like this.

```
template <class T>
bool Vector<T>:: empty() const {
    return _size == 0;
}
```

I just put inline into the class.

The assignment operator problem has been covered by @liv902

```
template<class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator = (const Vector<T> & v) {
    delete[] buffer;
    _size = v._size;
    Log = v.Log;
    _capacity = v._capacity;
    buffer = new T [_capacity];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
    return *this;
}
```

Basically you should not change the state of your object until you have guranteed that there are no expceptions can be thrown and leave your object in an incosistent state. This means your assignemnt should proceed in three stages.

1. Copy the state of the src class into temporary objects.
   This is because making the copy can throw an exception and thus you should not put your object into a state wheere it can be invalid.
2. Swap the state of you object with the temporary values.
   Swapping is an exception safe operation.
3. Now you can destroy the old state (which is in the temporary values).
   This can also throw an exception, but your object will be in a consistent state.

This techniques means you provide the "Strong (Transaction) Exception Guarantee" (You can look it up in google).

The easiest way to implement the above is to use the "Copy and Swap Idiom".

When you remove something from a std::vector.

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back() {
    _size--;
}
```

The destructor for that object is also called. This allows you free resources for non trivial resources (say T was a `std::shared_ptr<int>`) not calling the destructor means you are effectively retaining a reference to an object that could be freed.

It is perfectly valid to manually call the destructor of an object (In fact this is very normal when pared with placement new operation).

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::pop_back() {

    // You way want to do a check for empty() before calling the destructor.

    // Call the destructor.
    (reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer)[_size-1]).~T();

    // It is usual to prefer the pre decrement (and pre increment).
    --_size;
}
```

Just like a pop.
When you clear a vector you generally expect the destructor to all the members to be called.

```
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::clear() {
    _capacity = 0;
    _size = 0;
    buffer = 0;
    Log = 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like Visual Studio 2012 attempts to increase the capacity by `max (capacity + 50%, minimum capacity needed)`. But then again, Microsoft has been known to ignore standards.

Comment: @jliv902: That looks like 1.5x to me then (so not far off a 1.6x I suggested). But I don't think the standard actually specifies. It just defines the insertion (and some others) characteristics which should `amortized constant time`

Comment: @LokiAstari: The logic behind a growth factor of `1.5x` is that whenever the growth factor is less than the golden ratio, the vector should (in theory) be able to (in the long run) reuse previously allocated memory, while if the ratio is larger than the golden ratio, the new allocation will always request more memory than the sum of all previous allocations. See for example [this blog post](http://crntaylor.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/optimal-memory-reallocation-and-the-golden-ratio/) for further explanation.

Comment: @Mankarse: I am (somewhat) aware of golden ratio connection. That is why I said 1.6 [golden ratio](https://www.google.com/search?q=golden+ratio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)

Comment: @LokiAstari: I suppose my comment should have been directed at OP then.

Comment: @Mankarse: Though I admit I have no idea why the maths works.

Comment: @LokiAstari you should know that [this answer is being discussed on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5471/41243).

Comment: @MartinYork Quick q: "You are going to have a hard time making this work if the buffer is of type T. Every time you expand the buffer all the elements in the buffer will be initialized with T constructor." Why? I know that a char doesn't have a ctor. When you're saying expanding the buffer you're talking about placement new? If so, won't there be identical overhead for the `T` object since ultimately that's what's being created (we're just abstracting it using `char`s)? Thanks, great answer.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Here I am saying that the current version when you expend the buffer (when the buffer is type T*)  that the generated code will automatically default construct all the members in the buffer (before you copy from the old to new buffer). Now the problem with that is that T's constructor may be large (time or resources) and you are forcing the construction of these objects even if they may never be used.

Comment: Say your vector is at 1000 elements (no capacity left). You add one element the vector now reserves 2000 elements to allow for expansion. Using `T* buffer;`  and allocating a new buffer with `newBuffer = new [2000]();` You just created (and constructed) 2000 objects of type T. That's very expensive. Especially if you are going to move construct members the first 1000 from the old buffer and may never need to use 999 of the items in the new buffer? What happens if T is `std::vector` ? All those resources you just allocated which are never used.

Comment: Now the alternative is to use `char* buffer` and reserve space with `newBuffer = new [2000 * sizeof(T)];` Memory allocated; no time or resource wasted constructing members. Now You move construct by using in place new the old buffer to the new buffer. So only one move constructor called for each member copied (rather than a default construct followed by a move assignment). Also you have not wasted time constructing the 1000 elements that may never be used.

Answer (score 10):

- Using `log` to calculate capacity is very questionable. It forces a client to link the executable with `-lm`. I would not bother with `Log` at all: just double the `capacity` as needed.
- A repeated code in the constructors should be factored out.
- It is OK (and in fact preferable) to use `std::copy()` instead of loops.
- `pop_back()` must destroy a `buffer[size - 1]` object.
- `clear()` must `delete [] buffer`. Edit: it must destroy everything in the buffer. The buffer itself may stay. Thanks to [Loki Astari](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/507/loki-astari)
- All accessors (`begin`, `end`, `front`, `back`, `operator[]`) must have `const` versions as well.
- A choice of `unsigned int` for size parameters is questionable. A natural type for size is `size_t`.

PS: addressing the comment:

The [spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/) says

```
const T& front() const;
      T& front();
```

Both must be implemented. It is not the matter of convention: you want your class to be useful, that is, std algorithms should work with it - and they expect those methods.

Comment: +1 for some great points you've mentioned. I corrected everything you've recommended except the `log` stuff as STL vector regrows vector in the same manner http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ . Should I reconsider it, Sir?

Comment: Yes, the vector should grow exponentially, but it is not a reason to summon math library. It is more than enough to have a reasonable default capacity, and double it as needed. A very important guideline is to not force a client to pay for he's not asked for. I think you should reconsider.

Comment: Okay Sir :) Another question is I am returning front and back like `int& front() const` and `int& back() const`. Can I use `int front()` and `int back()` there? Will it violate the convention? if so, why?

Comment: See update (too long and too important for a comment).

Comment: Note sure about: `clear() must delete [] buffer.` It must delete all the members of the vector. But you do not need to deallocate the buffer.

Comment: I think the standard uses (1.6x) when expanding the buffer.

Comment: @LokiAstari The standard doesn't specify how large the expansion should be.

Comment: @Yuushi: You are correct I miss spoke. I meant some of the common implementations use 1.6x. Though I was corrected below by jliv902 who says that VisStudio 12 uses 1.5

Comment: The point about `-lm` is a very bad point. Why use the math library at all then? Not to mention that `libstdc++` automatically links with `-lm` and chances are `libc++` does as well.

Comment: 1) What is this `-lm` you speak of? C++ makes no mention of it. 2) I never had the need to link any C++ program I wrote with `-lm`, even when I made heavy use of "the math library"; can you elaborate what sequence of steps would lead to the need to "link the executable with `-lm`"?

Answer (score 8):

1. Use a `size_type`.

   What if one day, instead of an `unsigned int`, you wanted to use an `unsigned long`, or a `size_t`, or a `unsigned long long` for some reason. You would have to change multiple lines in your code. If anybody was using your `Vector` class then they would have to change their code as well.

   Defining a `size_type` would make it so that you only have to change one line of code and anyone using your `Vector` class would (hypothetically) not have to change any of their code at all.

   You can define a `size_type` like this:

   ```
   typedef unsigned int size_type ;
   ```

   Or if you have C++11:

   ```
   using size_type = unsigned int ; // C++11 only
   ```
2. Be mindful of [exception safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853243/c-do-you-really-write-exception-safe-code).

   For example, let's take a look at your copy-assignment operator.

   ```
   template<class T>
   Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator = (const Vector<T> & v) {
       delete[] buffer; // no throw (can cause undefined behavior)
       _size = v._size; // no throw
       Log = v.Log; // no throw
       _capacity = v._capacity; // no throw
       buffer = new T [_capacity]; // CAN THROW!!
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++) // no throw
           buffer[i] = v.buffer[i]; // no throw
       return *this; // no throw
   }
   ```

   Let's say I was using your Vector like this:

   ```
   Vector <int> v ;
   // Initialize v and add some elements
   // some other code...

   try {
       // copy-assignment operator
       // let's pretend it throws std::bad_alloc()
       v = someOtherVector ;

       // some other code...
   }

   // some other code...
   ```

   Assuming I handle the exception, `v` will now have an incorrect `_size`, `Log`, and `_capacity`.
3. Your copy-assignment operator does not check for self-assignment.

   Your program will invoke undefined behavior when you get to this part of your code:

   ```
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
       buffer[i] = v.buffer[i];
   ```

   Check out the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for a good way to tackle this problem.
4. Your member-variable names are inconsistent.

   You should follow a single convention.

   One way to do it:

   ```
   size_type _size;
   size_type _capacity;
   size_type _log;
   T* _buffer;
   ```

   Another way to do it:

   ```
   size_type m_size;
   size_type m_capacity;
   size_type m_log;
   T* m_buffer;
   ```

   There are a few other conventions. Just pick one and stick to it, and make sure you don't use any [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: +1 for a very informative answer. Now I am in a pos N dilemma whose answer I should accept? :P

Comment: @KaidulIslam You just posted this question an hour ago. I usually wait a week before accepting an answer (on Code Review only), but that's just me. I would upvote any answer you felt was helpful and accept the one that helped you the most.

Comment: Yes. Pending accepting a answer is a good idea as more opinion will come as codereview has no EXACT answer. But this snippet is very small and there are few scope to dig it. I will wait :)

Comment: @jliv902 Is the check for self assignment really necessary? When does self assignment actually happen? I doubt it happens even in 1/1,000,000 cases. However the extra overhead from the conditional if branching will always be computed!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are deleting `buffer` first, you have to check if `_size > 1`. If so, then you are using `delete[]`, otherwise just `delete`.

```
if(m_size >1)
        delete [] buffor;
        delete buffor;
```

Comment: I would also put the `delete[]` in curly braces for clarity, or at the very least use less indentation for the `delete`.

Comment: @Maciej Are you sure about that? The memory was allocated with `new[]`. So whatever its size `delete[]` and not `delete` should be called. Isn't that right?

Comment: This is simply not true. As @Nikos points out, the rule is simply to use `delete` if you used `new`, and `delete[]` if you used `new[]`.